# TODOs in files which names start with a dot are not displayed in the Tasks view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, task, aem, todo

Why are the TODOs in files which names start with a dot (e.g. ".content.xml") not displayed in the Tasks view in Eclipse?

I already know other tricks for fixing the problems that some TODOs are not displayed in the Tasks view (e.g. cleaning and rebuilding a project), but none of these tricks help regarding the TODOs which are located in XML files which names start with a dot. The TODOs which are located in files which names don't start with a dot are shown correctly in the Tasks view.

It seems that the eclipse task scanner ignores files which names start with a dot. Any ideas how to fix this?

I have already searched for solutions to this problem and have tried various configuration changes in eclipse, but nothing helped.
I use eclipse on Windows.

Comment: Well, in Unix-like operating systems a file starting with a dot means it's hidden. Don't name files starting with a dot if you don't want them to be hidden

Comment: @Ivo: I can’t choose how to name these files (e.g. ".content.xml"), because they are standard names of TouchUI components in AEM. But I would like to see the TODOs in them. I use Windows.